# Mathematical indices error in latex

Tags: pdftex, amsmath

I am new to LaTeX. I have a long paragraph which includes some mathematics symbols (indices and exponents). According to documents, I can use `^` and `_` for both functions. However, they fail until I add `\begin{gather}` and `\end{gather}`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\begin{document} 
 This is only test  

\[\int_a^b f(x)dx\] 


\begin{gather}
a_{xy}= b_2+ 7c_{tt}+ o^{yu}         %% This is OK inside of {gather section}
\end{gather}

%i_h is the data        %% error" Missing $ inserted." 
i^3                                 % error" Missing $ inserted." 
\end{document}
```

Should I use `gather` to encapsulate all texts that have math symbol?

If a paragraph is wrapped by `gather`, the whole paragraph would be in one line of the generated PDF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use mathemathics in TeX, you have to switch to *math mode*. There are several ways of doing that.

Inside a line of text you can use `$$`, like `$f(x) = ax^2 +bx+c$`. These are called *text formulas* and they even work in plain TeX.

*Display formulas* are typeset on a separate line:

- `$$f(x) = ax^2 +bx+c$$` (works in plain TeX as well)
- `\begin{displaymath}f(x) = ax^2 +bx+c\end{displaymath}`
- `\begin{equation}f(x) = ax^2 +bx+c\end{equation}`

For multi-line equations you can use the `eqnarray` environment. Environments are a LaTeX feature.

Since you are using the `amsmath` package which makes [specialized environments](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align.2A) for typesetting mathematics available, you might want to use `align` or `align*` environments instead of `displaymath` or `eqnarray`.

Comment: @RolandSmith: as addition: displaymath should not be used, if amsmath is loaded.

Comment: Please, note that `$$...$$` should *never* be used in LaTeX. Nor `eqnarray` that's buggy: for alignments there are `align`, `gather` and other environments provided by `amsmath`.

Comment: @MaxNoe `displaymath` is perfectly legal with `amsmath`, which however provides `equation*` that is more consistent.

Comment: Please have a look into the LaTeX-taboo:
http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf
`Warning: When using amsmath.sty you should never use the displaymath, eqnarray,
or eqnarray* environments because those are not supported by amsmath.sty. Otherwise this
would lead to inconsistent spacing`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have subscripts and superscripts in `text mode`, you have the `\textsuperscript` command, and with the `fixltx2e` package, `\textsubscript`. Here is a demo:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\begin{document} 
 This is only test  

\[\int_a^b f(x)dx\] 


\begin{gather}
a_{xy}= b_2+ 7c_{tt}+ o^{yu}         %% This is OK inside of {gather section}
\end{gather}

%i_h is the data        %% error" Missing $ inserted." 
i^3                                 % error" Missing $ inserted." 
\end{document}
```

[image]